# Keyboard Overlaps on Entry when using the SlideOverKit MenuContainerPage

Tags: xaml, xamarin.ios, xamarin.forms

I have added the MenuContainerPage of SlideOverKit on which we are using the Entry but when entry got the focus keyboard hide the entry in iOS. I also tried using the Xam.Plugins.Forms.KeyboardOverlap plugin, it only works when Page is inherited from ContentPage.

So could you please help me to resolve the issue.

Comment: Can't you just dismiss the keyboard?

Comment: No, I don't want to dismiss the keyboard. I want that Entry should be move  above the keyboard, so i can enter the text in Entry.

Comment: Can you set the placement of the entry according to the height of the keyboard?  So when entry is focused just have it move?

Comment: Here is a link to a page renderer to accomplish this:

https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/30336/popup-keyboard-hides-parts-of-the-ui-rather-than-resizing

Answer (score 0):

Create a ScrollView and add your Entry in the ScrollView. Then the keyboard will not hide the Entry.

In C# like this:

```
Content = new ScrollView {
    Content = new StackLayout {
        VerticalOptions = LayoutOptions.Center,
            Spacing = 10,
            Children = {

                //Other Controls...
                new Entry { }
        }
    }
};
```

In Xaml like this:

```
<ScrollView>
    <StackLayout>

        <!--Other Controls...-->
        <Entry />

    </StackLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

Comment: Thank you. I had already tried this. But on my page i wouldn't be able to add the ScrollView, because there is already grid with scroll is present on page.

Comment: Could you please provide the related layout xaml or C# code?